# Python dictionary list merging

Tags: python, list, set, structure, dictionary

I want to join the dictionaries in a list whose key 'user' are the same, but I don't realize how. for example:

```
[{'count2': 34, 'user': 2},
 {'count4': 233, 'user': 2},
 {'count2': 234, 'user': 4},
 {'count4': 344, 'user': 5}]
```

would become:

```
[{'count2': 34, 'count4': 233, 'user': 2 },
 {'count2': 234, 'user': 4},
 {'count4': 344, 'user': 5}]
```

I searched extensively without found something similar in stack overflow, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would a dictionary indexed by user work? That is, `{2: {'count2': 34...}, 4: {'count2':234...}` etc? It makes more intuitive sense and would probably be easier to construct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. But there are probably more efficient ways to do it (and in fewer lines)...

```
# Input
a=[{'count2': 34, 'user': 2},
 {'count4': 233, 'user': 2},
 {'count2': 234, 'user': 4},
 {'count4': 344, 'user': 5}]

# Get set of unique users
u=list(set([x['user'] for x in a]))

# Create a blank list of dictionaries for the result
r=[{}] * len(u)

# Iterate over input and add the dictionaries together
for x in a:
    r[u.index(x['user'])] = dict(r[u.index(x['user'])].items() + x.items())


>>> r
[{'count2': 34, 'user': 2, 'count4': 233}, {'count2': 234, 'user': 4}, {'count4': 344, 'user': 5}]
```

Comment: Shouldn't the input be called `a` instead of `i`?

Comment: @mgilson: yeah, thanks. I've fixed it. I got a bit muddled with my copy/pasteing from my test terminal

Comment: what if I want the result dictionaries from the list to have the same keys with zeroes as the default value? thanks in advance

Comment: To do that you would be best off finding all of the unique versions of the 'count*' keys and then initialising them to 0 in the `r=[{}] * len(u)` line.

Answer (score 7):

```
from collections import defaultdict

dl = [{'count2': 34, 'user': 2},
{'count4': 233, 'user': 2},
{'count2': 234, 'user': 4},
{'count4': 344, 'user': 5}]
print dl

dd = defaultdict(dict)
for d in dl:
    dd[d['user']].update(d)
print dd.values()
```

Comment: You can replace `for k, v in d.items(): dd[u][k] = v` with `dd[u].update(d)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can sort then use groupby, then merge it

```
from itertools import groupby
def merge(dicts):
    ret = {}
    for d in dicts:
        ret.update(d)
    return ret

d = [...]
sorted_d = sorted(d, key=lambda x: x['user'])
grouped_d = itertools.groupby(sorted_d, key=lambda x: x['user'])
print [merge(y[1]) for y in grouped]
```

Answer (score 1):

In the array:

```
[{'count2': 34, 'user': 2},
 {'count4': 233, 'user': 2},
 {'count2': 234, 'user': 4},
 {'count4': 344, 'user': 5}]
```

such that `a = {'count2': 34, 'user': 2}` and `b = {'count4': 233, 'user': 2}`,

```
dict(a.items() + b.items())
```

will return:

```
{'count2': 34, 'count4': 233, 'user': 2 }
```

EDIT: Working for groups:

http://codepad.org/ObWT2Hl3

Comment: That merges only two of them, not groups.

Comment: What I mean is that it requires explicitly stating which groups should be added together; it would fall short if there were hundreds of dictionaries that needed to be combined. It's part of the solution, though.